# Why not prepopulated value being set as value in Autocomplete Material UI using controller of react-hook-form

Tags: autocomplete, material-ui, yup, react-hook-form

I am using controller component of `react-hook-form` to call material UI autocomplete.

When I'm passing `defaultValue` parameter then it is populating in field but when click on submit button then showing validation error message:
[image]

```
shared_with_users must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `{ "value": "571998", "label": "\"Satyendra Kumar\"" }`). If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`
```

Here is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-tree-9e2js?file=/src/App.js

Autocomplete is coming after selection of last select box. I am using yup for form validation.

Please suggest the fixes.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed now.
Problem was uncontrolled component, when i created controlled component then it started working properly.

Here is my updated code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-tree-9e2js?file=/src/App.js